# Rails undefined local variable or method `current_user' for Order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, undefined

Hi I have came into an issue in my website when a user is checking out. All users have a cart when a user is created or signs in. Theres an instance of current_user in a sessions helper thats included in the applications controller. When a user goes to place their order after they placed items in their cart I see the error "undefined local variable or method 'current_user' for #" This is the code that is in the Order model

```
 def add_line_items_from_cart(cart)
    current_user.cart.line_items each do |item|
      item.cart_id = nil
      line_items << item
    end
```

I am a bit confused by this because I thought current_user.cart would be working. 
Here is my Orders controller

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  include CurrentCart
  before_action :set_cart, only: [:new, :create]
  before_action :set_order, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def new
    if current_user.cart.line_items.empty?
        redirect_to root_path, notice: "Your cart is empty"
            return
        end
        @order = Order.new
    end

  def create
    @order = Order.new(order_params)
    @order.add_line_items_from_cart(@cart)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @order.save
        current_user.cart.destroy
        session[:cart_id] = nil

        format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice:
              'Thank you for your order.'}
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created,
              location: @order}
        else
          format.html {render action: 'new'}
          format.json {render json: @order.errors,
                status: :unprocessable_entity}
      end
    end
  end
  private
  def order_params
    params.require(:order).permit(:name, :address, :email, :pay_type)
    end
end
```

and my order partial for when a user can place an order

```
<%= form_for(@order) do |f|%>
<% if @order.errors.any?%>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <h2> <%= pluralize(@order.errors.count, "error")%>
      prohibited this order from being saved:</h2>
      <ul>
        <% @order.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg%></li>
        <%end%>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <%end%>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :name %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :name, size: 40%>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :address %><br>
      <%= f.text_area :address, rows: 3, cols: 40%>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :email %><br>
      <%= f.email_field :email, size: 40%>
    </div>    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :pay_type %><br>
      <%= f.select :pay_type, Order::PAYMENT_TYPES,
                prompt: 'Select a payment method'%>
      </div>
      <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit 'Place Order' %>
      </div>
      <%end%>
```

If anyone can explain to me why this isn't working that would be very helpful.

Comment: Are you using Devise? current_user is a devise helper that is only available to controllers

Comment: Nope I'm using bcrypt I created a current user method myself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Theres an instance of current_user in a sessions helper thats included in the applications controller.

No part of that is available in your model layer. Your models have no access to controller variables or helpers. You cannot use `current_user` inside your model layer unless you specifically pass it in as a parameter to whatever method you're in.

Comment: just found my error it was something silly. thanks for the help